# Add 2D images in scene using A-frame

Tags: image, aframe

Is it possible to add 2D images like below in my scene. I'm using [aframe](/questions/tagged/aframe) *(version 0.5.0)* in combination with [angular2](/questions/tagged/angular2).

[image: Search icon]

I've tried to watch inside the inspector tools *(<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>)* it there is an option to add this but nothing found to add an image component.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<a-image src="image.png">`

Answer (score 1):

Add a plane entity to the scene first and then attach your image to it as a texture.

See the A-Frame documentation for more details:
https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/primitives/a-plane.html